# Saving File in internal memory and reading through intent

Tags: java, android

I want to download a file from URL and save it to the internal memory. Once file is saved in internal memory I want to fire an Intent to open it in apps.

```
**Following is the code to download the file and save in internal memory:**

 private void getPDFContent(String myUrl, String sfilename) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput(sfilename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            URL u = new URL(myUrl);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

**Following is the code to read:**

public void readInternalStorageOption() {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            String filePath = getApplication().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator + "test.pdf";
            File f = new File(filePath);
            if (f.exists()) {
                Uri internal = Uri.fromFile(f);
                intent.setDataAndType(internal, "application/pdf");
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {

        }
    }
```

Issue is that file is saved successfully but when I try to open it via intent I got an error that file cannot be opened. Please suggest any solution for the same.

Comment: By internal memory, do you mean the phone's integrated memory that is accessible by all apps with the right permissions? Because that is msot commonly reffered to among developers as external storage because it is outside your apps protected space

Comment: Indeed external memory should be used instead. Or use a FileProvider.